# C++ Using std::set<> in std::map<>

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, set

I'd like to use std::set in std::map

I haven't much exp with std:: containers, so i am not sure if i am using it right.
I am trying to process set of values and in each set is another set of values.

```
map<string, set<string> > data_map;

data_map["KEY1"].insert("VAL1");
data_map["KEY1"].insert("VAL2");

data_map["KEY2"].insert("VAL1");
data_map["KEY2"].insert("VAL3");
```

I get error here when i try to access set in map (inner for-cycle)

```
error: no match for call to ‘(std::set<std::basic_string<char> >) ()’|
error: no match for call to ‘(std::set<std::basic_string<char> >) ()’|


for( map<string, set<string> >::iterator mip = data_map.begin();mip != data_map.end(); ++mip) {
    for ( set<string>::iterator sit = mip->second().begin(); sit != mip->second().end(); ++sit )
        cout << *sit << endl;

}
```

Could you please tell me how i can iterate all values?

Comment: You just want `second`, not `second()` (it's a field of `std::pair`, not a method). Does that fix your issue?

Comment: @JeremyRoman I am sorry, you're right. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mip->second().begin()
```

should be

```
mip->second.begin()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use mip->second not mip->second().
I would recommed you to use auto in a for-each loop.

```
for(auto mip : data_map)
{  
    //Do another loop to get the values of your set, to get the set from the map use get<1>(mip);

}
```

Its better to read it that way and less space for errors.

Comment: If you're going to use `auto`, you're presumably in C++11. You might as well use the range-based for at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call the set like a function.

```
for( map<string, set<string> >::iterator mip = lines.begin();mip != lines.end(); ++mip) {
    for ( set<string>::iterator sit = mip->second.begin(); sit != mip->second.end();
          ++sit )
        cout << *sit << endl;
```